# Why this equivalence class?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$. Why is the equivalence class of $a\in G$ under right congruence, $\{ x\in G | x\equiv_r a\}$?

Shouldn't it be $\{x\in G|a\equiv_r x\}$? Because

> The equivalence class of an element $a$ is defined as the set
>   
> $[a]=\{x\in X|a\sim x\}$

Comment: Equivalence relations are symmetric.

Comment: Right, from this?: $\forall a,b\in X; a\sim b \Rightarrow b\sim a$

Comment: Andreas's point is that $\{ x\in G | x\equiv_r a\}$ and $\{x\in G|a\equiv_r x\}$ are always equal, because $x\equiv_r a$ holds if and only if $a\equiv_r x$ holds, because $\equiv_r$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x\equiv_r a \text{ is equivalent to: } a\equiv_r x$$

**EDIT:**

Given a set $X$ and an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$:

For every two elements $a$ and $b$ in $X$, if $a \sim b$, then $b \sim a$.

Answer (score 0):

A relation is equivalent, so $\forall a,b\in X; a\sim b\Rightarrow b\sim a$.